# Symfony2: How to add a form created using factory builder into another form's collection type field?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.7

I am creating forms from yml at runtime. I go through the elements in yml file and add appropriate fields to the form. The root form is created like this

```
$form = $factory->createBuilder("form", $this->userData);
```

The yml will have an option to define a collection field as well. 
The collection field requires `type` option to be supplied which must be of type `string`, `Symfony\Component\Form\ResolvedFormTypeInterface`, `Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface`

But since I am building the embedded form as well at runtime, I wont have a type and neither `FormTypeInterface`

Here is the sample code of what I need to do

```
$options = isset($config["options"]) ? $config["options"]: [];
if ($config['type'] == 'collection') {
    $options['type'] = $this->buildForm($options['template'], $factory);
    unset($options['template']);
    $form->add($config["name"], $config["type"], $options);
}
```

Here `$options['template']` is how the type for the embedded form is defined in yml file. So that form is also build at runtime. How do I embed it in the root form?

Edit:
In fact, if I only have a single field, say `email` in the collection field, then it works fine. But the yml spec will allow users to define multiple fields within collection fields. In symfony, this would be done by defining the embedded form type and setting `type` option of collection field type to that form type. But how do I do it when creating forms at runtime?

Comment: I would implement strategy pattern. For each of the types defined in yml, I would implement a certain class that adds the particular form type to the root form. These classes would implement an interface with probably only one method, e.g. `addType()`. It would also accept the root form as a constructor argument, so it could add the type. Then I would expand this for the collection type in the same manner.

Comment: There are going to be thousands of these yml files and I will need to render them at runtime. Theres no option to create thousands of classes.. Also PHP does not allow you to define classes based on interface at runtime!

Comment: Just an idea, maybe helps. What I mean, one class per form type (field). There is a limited set of form types, e.g. text, choice, textarea,.. A class per each of those. Then, a root form class can use an event subscriber and add those fields based on data supplied, for pre_set_data event. In your case the set of strings coming from yml. If you had not so far, check the dynamic forms in Symfony: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: "Thousands of files", OK, each form can be made in runtime based on some external definition. Those definitions can be passed as option/s to the generic root form class (you'll need to add more options to form type class).

Comment: @ĐuroMandinić thanks! I had solved it somewhat like that before I went to sleep last night! See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by defining a form type class, that builds the form at runtime. The config(form design) is passed into the constructor and `buildForm` adds respective fields according to the design.

```
class RuntimeFormType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $config;

    /**
     * RuntimeFormType constructor.
     * @param string $name
     * @param array $config
     */
    public function __construct($name, array $config)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        foreach($this->config as $config){
            $options = isset($config["options"]) ? $config["options"]: [];

            if($config['type'] == 'image'){
                $options['data_class']  = null;
                $options['multiple']  = false;

                $options['attr'] = [
                    "accept" => "images/*"
                ];

                $builder->add($config["name"], "file", $options);
            }else{
                $builder->add($config["name"], $config["type"], $options);
            }
        }
    }


    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

and in the builder, when the type is `collection` type initialize this form type and add to the root form.

```
if ($config['type'] == 'collection') {
    $template = $options['template'];

    unset($options['template']);
    $options['type'] = new RuntimeFormType($config["name"], $template);

    $form->add($themeConfig["name"], $themeConfig["type"], $options);
}
```